# PHP code explanation question.

Tags: php

I don't know if this id the place to ask this question so be kind if I am wrong.

I was wondering if someone can explain to me in detail what the following 3 code snippets below do.

Snippet 1

```
if($str !== mb_convert_encoding(mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-32')){
    $str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Snippet 2

```
$str = preg_replace('`&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|uml|circ|grave|ring|cedil|slash|tilde|caron|lig);`i', '\\1', $str);
```

Snippet 3

```
$str = preg_replace(array('`[^a-z0-9]`i','`[-]+`'), '-', $str);
```

Here is the full code below for reference.

```
function to_permalink($str){
    if($str !== mb_convert_encoding(mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8'), 'UTF-8', 'UTF-32')){
        $str = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-8');
    }
        $str = htmlentities($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $str = preg_replace('`&([a-z]{1,2})(acute|uml|circ|grave|ring|cedil|slash|tilde|caron|lig);`i', '\\1', $str);
        $str = html_entity_decode($str, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'UTF-8');
        $str = preg_replace(array('`[^a-z0-9]`i','`[-]+`'), '-', $str);
        $str = strtolower(trim($str, '-'));
        return $str;
}
```

Comment: have you tried to test it to see what they do?

Answer (score 6):

Snippet 1 makes sure the string is in UTF-8 encoding.

Snippet 2 converts all special characters to their base form (ie, 'é' -> 'e').

Snippet 3 will convert spaces to hyphens (-).

All in all, taking into account the function's name and content, I'd say it is used to make URL friendly links, for example, convert

> I discovered a new french word: église

to

> i-discovered-a-new-french-word-eglise

Usually used for SEO.

Answer (score 0):

Many of your questions can be answered by looking up what the functions do in your code.

Go here to get started: http://php.net/docs.php

Answer (score 0):

Snippet #1: Checking if the string is valid UTF-8 data by round-trip converting it from source-> UTF-32 -> UTF-8. If the result is NOT the same as the input, then try to let the MB library determine the input encoding and output as UTF-8 regardless. Seems to be rather much work for little gain.

Snippet #2:  Looks for a series of potential character entities (accented characters, in this case), and strips off the leading `&` and trailing `;` if it matches and adds a backslash. So `&AElig;` becomes `\AElig`.

Snippet #3: Converts any character which is NOT `a-z` or `0-9` or a sequence of 1 or more `-` into a single `-`.